# Winmerge ignores file filters when showing "Left Unique Items"?

Tags: winmerge

In WinMerge (2.14.0.0) I've chosen to use a filter. This filter contains:

```
name: Test
desc: Test
def: include
d: \\www\\orders$
```

I'm comparing "D:\TEST\www\" with "D:\www\".

This directory exists: D:\www\orders\xyz\

This directory does not exist: D:\TEST\www\orders\

I have View > "Show Right Unique Items" checked. When I compare the directories the result, in part, shows:

"Right only: D:\www\orders" in the Comparison Result column.

But should it not be ignoring directory "www\orders"? Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I should note that View > "Show Skipped Items" is *not* checked.

Answer (score 0):

Ooops, think I've got the answer. It seems that the filter path must start inside the directory being compared.

So if comparing d:\www and you want to ignore d:\www\orders, the filter must only be:

```
d: \\orders$
```

And not: d: \www\orders$